# Why can't `su` be used to switch to users with empty password?

Tags: users, login, password, su, accounts

Create a new account called `test`:

```
$ sudo useradd test
```

`test` doesn't have a password right now. So

```
$ su test
```

doesn't work. If you try, you're asked for `test`'s password. It doesn't have one. That's not the same as its password being empty so if you enter an empty password by pressing enter, you get message "su: Authentication failure".

The same is true if you switch to a tty and try to log in as `test`: An empty password isn't accepted.

Now assign `test` an empty password:

```
$ sudo passwd -d test
```

You can now log in as `test` on a tty by providing the empty string as the password. However, if you try

```
$ su test
```

again, you still get the message "su: Authentication failure" the session doesn't switch to the user `test`.

Why is this?

Comment: Whats the output of `ldd /bin/su | grep -q pam && echo OK`?

Comment: For me after `sudo passwd -d test` I was able to `su - test` without a password using a non-root account. Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @heemayl The output is simply "OK".

Comment: @Thomas I don't really see the point of a single dash between "su" and "test". Did you maybe want to put 2 dashes there? Anyways, it doesn't work for me either way. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `su - ` starts a login shell. For more details look up the manpage of  `su`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output of `ldd /bin/su`, the `su` binary is compiled with the `pam` libraries (`libpam*`), so the authentication, account management, session initiation etc stuffs will be managed by `pam`.

The following is how a typical Ubuntu system's `su` is managed by `pam`, you should find similar approach if you are using another distro.

The `pam`  rules for `su` are defined in the file `/etc/pam.d/su`. This file also includes the `common-auth`, `common-passwd`, `common-session` files from same directory as common templates for covering the tasks their name suggest (and used in other `pam` enabled services).

On my system, at the bottom of `/etc/pam.d/su` i have:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

The preceding lines do not deal with the null password checking, it is mainly the job of `pam_unix` module.

Now `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` has:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

From `man pam_unix`:

> nullok
>
> The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok argument overrides this default and allows any user with a
>              blank password to access the service.
>
> nullok_secure
>
> The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok_secure argument overrides this default and allows any user
>              with a blank password to access the service as long as the value of PAM_TTY is set to one of the values found in /etc/securetty.

as you can see if the `nullok_secure` option is set, the unless the environment variable `PAM_TTY` is set in the mentioned manner, the user with null password will not be permitted to login using `su`.

So to allow any user with null password to do `su`, you need to have the `nullok` argument to the `pam_unix` module:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
```

this is insecure as the `common-auth` file is used by many other services, even for only `su` this should not be done. (For the sake of testing you can set it once and then revert back to original. Although if you want to do the test, it's better to incorporate all the logics in `/etc/pam.d/su` file, and amend any changes afterwards rather than messing with any `common-*` file)

Comment: `/etc/securetty` also kicks in (for empty passwords) if getting their from SSH, since no `/dev/pts/*` is listed there in Debian 10. This seems to had been changed, since I was able to login at least from the first pseudo terminal with Debian 9.
Thanks a lot for the expressive answer and the link to `man sercuretty` (linking to `pam_securetty`).

Answer (score 0):

From `man useradd`:

```
-p, --password PASSWORD 
The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
```

You didn't use `--password`, so the userid was given a special, "disabled" password. Not the same as an empty password.

It would be a Security Hole the other way.

Comment: This is not what he is asking. He did manage to correctly set the user password to empty, but still cannot log in from `su`, although he can log in from the tty

Comment: Thank you, @IW16. I set the password to the empty string using the command  `sudo passwd -d test` so there is this intermediate step where neither login via `su` nor via tty works so people know that I know the difference between the password being the empty string and the password not being set.